# How to send and receive custom data through Airdrop

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an application that I want to implement airdrop in to and I want this application to be able to send a custom data set through airdrop to another iPhone that has the same app installed. I then want the receiving device to automatically open and handle the data.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 4):

To send the file you must use `UIActivityViewController` to be able to use AirDrop

To be able to receive the file and open it with the application you need to register a Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs) type.

[System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

> UTIs (short for Uniform Type Identifiers) is Apple’s answer to
>   identify data handled within the system. In brief, a uniform type
>   identifier is a unique identifier for a particular type of data or
>   file. For instance, com.adobe.pdf represents a PDF document and
>   public.png represents a PNG image. You can find the full list of
>   registered UTIs here. Application that is capable of opening a
>   specific type of file has registered to handle that UTI with the iOS.
>   So whenever that type of file is opened, iOS hands off that file to
>   the specific app.
>
> The system allows multiple apps to register the same UTI. In this
>   case, iOS will prompt user with the list of capable apps for opening
>   the file. For example, when you share a PDF document, you may
>   experience the following screen in the receiving device:

**How To Import and Export App Data**

https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/ios-adding-a-custom-uti/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/3109-email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/importing-data-via-custom-file-types-in/